# Minecraft sound(ogg) files disappeared in 1.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had Minecraft 1.7.4 there were ogg files of all music (including records like cat.ogg calm.ogg)
But when I uninstalled 1.7.4 and installed 1.8 those files disappeared .
1.8 has those music because when I play the game put music disc in jukebox I can hear the music. but where are the ogg files ?

In 1.7.4 they were in assets folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to find a sound file

1. Open `\.minecraft\assets\indexes\<version>.json`. `<version>` can be `1.7.10`, `1.8`, `14w25b`, etc.
2. In the index file, you can find a organized list of assets and some informations(hash and size) about them. `cave9.ogg` for example,

   > "minecraft/sounds/ambient/cave/cave9.ogg": {
   >    **"hash"**: **"b463fa47816fe9a5dfe508093150e647403e4db6"**,
   >    "size": 27096
   >   }

   has a hash value of `b463fa47…`. Remember first 2 digits(in this case `b4`).
3. The actual sound file is located at `.minecraft\assets\objects\<first 2 digits>\` with a filename being a `<hash>` without any extension. For example, `cave9.ogg` is located at `.minecraft\assets\objects\b4\` with a filename `b463fa47816fe9a5dfe508093150e647403e4db6` without extension.

Comment: Yes i saw many n number of files without extension. Will renaming them to proper name will give me the ogg file?

Comment: Just in case, I recommend that you make a copy of that file and rename it. The content of the file is already proper ogg bitstream but some music players don't play them properly when extension is not specified.

Comment: Yeah!! It worked. At last my favourite cat.ogg is playing. thanks